# What can I do to perfect this water wave with SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, wave

I'm trying to build water wave box with SVG. Though I can do it with image.png but I want to achieve it with svg too. I don't know if it is possible. The svg is not continuously linked.

I tried the code below, I want a continuously moving wave.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section .content {
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #3586ff;
}

section .content {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

section .wave {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

section .wave1 {
  animation: wave linear 30s infinite;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 1;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  bottom: 0;
}

section .wave2 {
  animation: wave2 linear 5s infinite;
  z-index: 999;
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation-delay: -5s;
  bottom: 10px;
}

section .wave3 {
  animation: wave linear 30s infinite;
  z-index: 998;
  opacity: 0.2;
  animation-delay: -2s;
  bottom: 15px;
}

section .wave4 {
  animation: wave2 linear 5s infinite;
  z-index: 997;
  opacity: 0.7;
  animation-delay: -5s;
  bottom: 20px;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes wave2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>

  <section>

    <div class="content">

      <h2>

        Wavy Header Tut

      </h2>

      <p>

        lareDiscussion Zone : beards & hijabs A brother wrote in asking us to cover this topic. He said that these days women do not want a man with a beard...

      </p>

    </div>

    <svg class="wave wave1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">

   <path fill="white" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L60,117.3C120,107,240,85,360,96C480,107,600,149,720,165.3C840,181,960,171,1080,160C1200,149,1320,139,1380,133.3L1440,128L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>

   </svg>

    <svg class="wave wave2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">

   <path fill="white" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L60,117.3C120,107,240,85,360,96C480,107,600,149,720,165.3C840,181,960,171,1080,160C1200,149,1320,139,1380,133.3L1440,128L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>

   </svg>

    <svg class="wave wave3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">

   <path fill="white" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L60,117.3C120,107,240,85,360,96C480,107,600,149,720,165.3C840,181,960,171,1080,160C1200,149,1320,139,1380,133.3L1440,128L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>

   </svg>

    <svg class="wave wave4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">

   <path fill="white" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L60,117.3C120,107,240,85,360,96C480,107,600,149,720,165.3C840,181,960,171,1080,160C1200,149,1320,139,1380,133.3L1440,128L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path>

   </svg>

  </section>

  <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of one direction, you could move the waves back and forth for some troubled waters. With javascript you could animate the SVGs themself by manipulating the paths. Or create a "ring": 2 or 3 images, as soon as on leaves the screen on the left remove it and add it again on the right side.

Comment: Show me how, the code

Comment: CSS in both directions should go somewhat like this `@keyframes wave { 0% { transform: translateX(0%); } 50% { transform: translateX(100%); } 100% { transform: translateX(0%); } }` (not tested)